# Who passes the Context as a method parameter to the Constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I want to know who does call/create constructor of `PageModel`-derived class (in my case `IndexModel`).
Seems to me that by each request to a razor page, the class which is provided to the `RazorPage` via `@model` is instantiated, also wanna know who supplies the constructor parameter context, which is the EF Context:

```
public IndexModel(RazorPagesMovie.Models.RazorPagesMovieContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency Injection (DI) framework in ASP.NET is responsible for creating your `IndexModel`.

DI creates instances and provides as parameters classes that have been registered to the service provider on startup in `ConfigureServices()`

What happens on a request, is that

- ASP.NET creates your `IndexModel` by asking the DI for it. This is basically the same as calling `services.GetService<IndexModel>()`. Your pagemodels have been registered to the DI container automatically for you
- Whatever arguments your `IndexModel` constructor has (there can be as many as you need), will get filled in by the DI as long as they have been registered. If there are any non-registered types as arguments, an exception is thrown

In this case, if the code you listed works you have a line registering `RazorPagesMovieContext` somewhere on `ConfigureServices()`.

Read more about DI in asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Note the section about service lifetimes as well.

Comment: Isn't it required to use `ServiceProvider` and `GetService` to get dependency injection services?

Comment: Yes you can do that manually, and that is what asp.net does for you under the hood when handling a request

Comment: You can try this out by creating a custom class, registering it as a service in ConfigureServices() and adding it as an argument to your IndexModel

Comment: When is it necessary to get the service through `GetService()` and not automatically as method parameter?

Comment: What is the syntax to register a custom class?

Comment: You normally would not need to use `GetService()` ever, that's what the frameworks are there for. The page i linked describes using the DI (registering and using classes) in detail, basically the only line you need is `services.AddTransient<MyClass>()`